# кузнец- кузница

Tags: грамматика

прошу прощения, ребенок задал вопрос- не смогла ответить: "Почему кузнец пишется через е, а кузница - через И?"
буду благодарна за помощь...это чередование в суффиксе? или как?

Comment: Разные суффиксы - в мужском роде пишется "е", в женском - "и". http://russkiy-na-5.ru/rules/52

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!просто огромное и за выход на сайт с этими правилами!! я искала в гугле, но так и не нашла

Answer (score 3):

Суффикс "**-ец**" имеет место при образовании существительных, как правило, мужского и среднего рода, суффикс "**-иц-**" - женского и среднего. А в нашем случае - мужской и женский род. Изредка встречаются и парные (различающиеся по смыслу только родом) слова с этими суффиксами: истец - истица.

Comment: _Суффикс "-ец" имеет место при образовании существительных **только** мужского и среднего рода_ === Иногда суффикс "ец" встречается и у существительных женского рода: 

ХИТРЕЦА (о некоторой доле хитрости, лукавства у кого-л.); 

НАГЛЕЦА (некоторая доля наглости);

КИСЛЕЦА (кислинка).

Comment: Спасибо, уберу "только".

Comment: большое спасибо!! я крайне признательна за ответ (исчерпывающий), и ОПЕРАТИВНОСТЬ!!!! вы - молодцы!!

Comment: @slava1947 : Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на употребление этих трёх слов в женском роде?

Comment: _Victor Bazarov: не могли бы дать ссылку на употребление этих трёх слов в женском роде?_ === Ну а какой же ещё род может у них быть, как не женский? Примеры употребления:

_Потапов, щурясь с **хохлацкой хитрецой**, посмотрел вверх на свесившегося Нержина. ===  Как-нибудь! ― с **лёгкой наглецой** ответил Нейман. ===  Охра игольчатая, сухая. Чуть с **муравьиною кислецой**._